# MySQL Join two tables with dynamic variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-maps, full-text-search

I have two functions, one for searching (fulltext searching) that returns best matches, and one for finding nearest location from current lat/lng.

The end result will be a search function to find the nearest store from where you are.

Search:

```
SELECT *,MATCH(name) AGAINST('*McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `score_name_0`, MATCH(`city`)   
AGAINST('McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `score_city_0` FROM `stores` 

WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('*McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR 
MATCH (`city`) AGAINST('McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY  (`score_name_0` + `score_city_0`) DESC
```

Finding nearest:

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('.$lat.')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - 
radians('.$long.')) + sin(radians('.$lat.')) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance 

FROM pinpoints 
INNER JOIN stores WHERE stores.id=pinpoints.store  HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT *,MATCH(name) AGAINST('*McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `score_name_0`, 
MATCH(`city`) AGAINST('McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `score_city_0` 

FROM `stores` 
JOIN pinpoints ON (3959 * acos(cos( radians(".$lat.")) * cos(radians(pinpoints.lat)) * cos(radians(pinpoints.lng) - 
radians(".$long.")) + sin( radians(".$lat.")) * sin(radians(pinpoints.lat)))) AS distance 

WHERE stores.id=pinpoints.id 
AND MATCH(name) AGAINST('*McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR 
MATCH (`city`) AGAINST('McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance, (`score_namn_0` + `score_stad_0`) DESC
```

Been stuck for quite some time, and can't seem to figure out a good way to combine them both so it finds the nearest match and sorts it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have things all over the place, I haven't tested this but it should work ...

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT *, MATCH(name) AGAINST('*McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `score_name_0`, 
            MATCH(`city`) AGAINST('McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `score_city_0`,
        (3959 * acos(cos( radians(".$lat.")) * cos(radians(pinpoints.lat)) * cos(radians(pinpoints.lng) - radians(".$long.")) + sin( radians(".$lat.")) * sin(radians(pinpoints.lat)))) AS distance
        FROM `stores` 
            JOIN pinpoints ON stores.id=pinpoints.id
        WHERE stores.id=pinpoints.id 
            AND (MATCH(name) AGAINST('*McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR 
            MATCH (`city`) AGAINST('McDonalds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
) AS tmp_tbl
WHERE distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance ASC, (`score_namn_0` + `score_stad_0`) DESC
```

Comment: Worked with a few modifications. Great, thank you! Sorry for the messy code!